# React.JS Best Way to Back Up State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

In my application somehow my state is destroyed when a component is rendered, so I placed the state outside the class and I change every `setState` to my own defined method that change the state.

Here is my code

```
let theState = {//the state properties}
class Foo extends Component{
  //the method is used to change the state, and setState to trigger rendering
  updateState(data){
        theState = {...theState,...data}
        console.log('sate update',{theState})
        this.setState(theState)
    }
}
```

this is ok, but the problem is when we are talking about reusability, I don't want to write the `updateState` method on every component, is there any better solution for this?

Comment: use function based react component which as the useEffect. where it is easy to handle this scenario

Comment: you can re-use state login using hooks, check this link https://egghead.io/courses/reusable-state-and-effects-with-react-hooks

Comment: Can you post more of the code so we can try and diagnose why the state is disappearing? You shouldn't have to manually back-up state like this.

Comment: @Tim i'm working with a team, so one of my team member changed the codabase from component based to react hooks based, and i dont want to refactor almost all of my code using functional component

Answer (score 0):

To use state in a class based component you need to use a constructor and then use `this.state = {}`. You then can update the state by calling `this.setState({})` in your component. As an example:

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {foo: "thing"};
  }
```

Alternatively, if you are using React ^16 you can use a functional component and React hooks. In this case your code would look something like:

```
const Foo = () -> {
  const [data, setdata] = React.useState()

  const updateState = (update) => {
    setData({...data, ...update}) //assuming it is an update or
    setData({update}) //assuming you want to replace the values
  }

}
```

State is only applicable at local (component) level unless you introduce an application state manager like Redux.